# how to prove that supremum of functions is intersection of epi

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I have some problems proving the following:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow ( -  \infty, \infty]$,
$f_i: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow ( -  \infty, \infty], \, i \in I$ be convex functions. Prove that $f = sup_{i \in I} f_i$ if and only if $ \text{epi} f = \bigcap_{i \in I} \text{epi} f_i$.

I managed to show the first direction. But i have troubles showing the back direction (see image). I don't know how to get from the epi to the definition of f.

I would be grateful about some help!

Here's what i got so far

[image]

Comment: What, specifically are your problems in probing the Problem Statement. We have no clue, unless you tell us more, what those problems are, if you even tried, and if so, where exactly did you get stuck.  You need to say more about what your problems are in getting a start on this.  Please understand, this site is not designed to do someone's work for them.  So please edit to had more background, source of the question, why is it an interesting question, etc.

Comment: Well, i wrote down the definitions of the epi and the convex functions. And i have no idea how to go forward from there...

Comment: I also mentioned you can let us know about you; what are you studying? What topic or section are you studying, in which this question arose?  Can you provide definitions of convex functions and "epi"?  Because this question requires you are fluent in the relevant definitions, which is different that "assignment".  Is there something conceptual you are not getting, that makes it difficult for you to understand this material.

Comment: But please realize, we are not a "do my work for me-solution-generating" service.  I've given you some good ideas about how you can improve your question.